# Stacktrace / Stackwalk for the current process and current thread with IDebug interfaces

Tags: windows, debugging, c++-cli, stack-trace

I want to use the `IDebugXXX interfaces` to get stack traces for some functions in my `local process` (no remote attaching).

Using this code the attach to the current process works, but the stack trace of the current thread alway contains `only one frame` like: 
`ntdll!ZwGetContextThread+0x00000012`

```
{
    IDebugClient* debugClient;
    IDebugControl4 *control4;

    ...

    int flags = DEBUG_ATTACH_NONINVASIVE | DEBUG_ATTACH_NONINVASIVE_NO_SUSPEND;
    debugClient->AttachProcess(0, myProcessId, flags);

    control4->SetExecutionStatus(DEBUG_STATUS_GO);


    ...

    // get the stack trace for the current thread
    control4->GetStackTrace(0, 0, 0, _stackFrames, ARRAYSIZE((_stackFrames)), &_uFramesFilled)

    // _uFramesFilled is always '1' for the current thread
}
```

**Edit:**
The application is written in C++/CLI and the results for the other threads at least contain more frames.

Comment: A managed debugger cannot obtain stack traces for unmanaged code.

Comment: It is a C++/CLI application

Comment: Then there's no point in making this complicated, just use the StackTrace class.

Comment: I need a mixed mode stacktrace, IDebug seems to be the right approach to me. Finally I need a function like GetTheStackHere() I can place anywhere in the code. May be you know a sample anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the `assert` sample in `WinDDK` I found out that there is the context missing the stack trace has to start from. After that (and adding `WaitForEvent(...)`) the trace works fine.

```
{
    ...

    // capture the context end convert it to debug '.crx' command
    char CxrCommand[64];
    CONTEXT myContext;
    ZeroMemory(&myContext, sizeof(CONTEXT));
    RtlCaptureContext(&myContext);
    sprintf_s(CxrCommand, 64, ".cxr 0x%p", &myContext);
    // capture the context end

    ...

    control4->WaitForEvent(DEBUG_WAIT_DEFAULT, INFINITE);

    //execute debugger command: ".cxr (Display Context Record)"
    control4->Execute(DEBUG_OUTCTL_IGNORE, CxrCommand, DEBUG_EXECUTE_NOT_LOGGED

    control4->GetStackTrace( .... )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me: ( caution: please check the return codes of these APIs )

I think what you are missing is: "WaitForEvent" call after "AttachProcess".

```
IDebugClient4 * debugClient;
IDebugControl4 * control4;
DEBUG_STACK_FRAME frames[10];
ULONG filled = 0;
ULONG pid = 7288;

DebugCreate( __uuidof(IDebugClient4), (void **)&debugClient );

debugClient->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDebugControl4), (void**)&control4 );

debugClient->AttachProcess(0, pid, DEBUG_ATTACH_NONINVASIVE | DEBUG_ATTACH_NONINVASIVE_NO_SUSPEND);

control4->WaitForEvent(DEBUG_WAIT_DEFAULT, INFINITE);

control4->GetStackTrace(0, 0, 0, &frames[0], 10, &filled);
```

Comment: thanks, I can test it on monday and will let know how it works

Comment: same behaviour, only one frame gets filled

Comment: finally got it, the context was missing also